# How can I add a variable to console.log?

Tags: javascript, console.log

I'm making a simple game in JavaScript but in the story I need it to say the players name. so what I have so far is:

```
var name = prompt("what is your name?");

console.log("story" name "story);
```

how do I do the second line? or there is another way I could do this. Is it possible to have 2 `console.log();` on 1 line in the console?

Comment: Are you just looking to concatenate strings together? What do you mean by "do the second line"?

Comment: ^ cogsmos, it doesn't matter now, my question has been answered

Comment: Glad you figured it out. In JavaScript the + can be used for arithmetic and also for joining two strings together (also called concatenation). Take a look here for some more details:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Then use `+` to combine strings:

```
console.log("story " + name + " story");
```

Answer (score 104):

You can use another console method:

```
let name = prompt("what is your name?");
console.log(`story ${name} story`);
```

Comment: Template strings are awesome. But provided someone uses ES6. Since in the example "var" is used (could be ES6 ofcourse) but don't think we can assume that here...

Comment: For those noobs like me, `\`` is different than `'` in javascript

Answer (score 92):

`console.log` takes multiple arguments, so just use:

```
console.log("story", name, "story");
```

If **name** is an `object` or an `array` then using multiple arguments is better than concatenation. If you concatenate an `object` or `array` into a string you simply log the type rather than the content of the variable.

But if **name** is just a primitive type then multiple arguments works the same as concatenation.

Comment: or also `console.log('story %s story',name);`

Comment: Minor thing, but if you're in a less conventional setting like Parse's Cloud Code sending an array or using %s doesn't work.. so you're forced to concatenate.

Comment: That's great @MuhammadUmer, I thought that was only a Python thing. In Python `%s` is the best method for concatenating strings, since you don't need to change the variable type first. I wonder if it's the same in JS?

Answer (score 69):

There are several ways of consoling out the variable within a string.

Method 1 :

```
console.log("story", name, "story");
```

Benefit : if name is a JSON object, it will not be printed as `"story" [object Object] "story"`

Method 2 :

```
console.log("story " + name + " story");
```

Method 3: When using ES6 as mentioned above

```
console.log(`story ${name} story`);
```

Benefit: No need of extra , or +

Method 4:

```
console.log('story %s story',name);
```

Benefit: the string becomes more readable.

Comment: @egemen what does freemarker have to do with it? It's an ECMAscript 2015 template literal

Comment: This is the best answer.

Answer (score 24):

When using ES6 you can also do this:

```
var name = prompt("what is your name?");
console.log(`story ${name} story`);
```

Note: You need to use backticks `` instead of "" or '' to do it like this.

Answer (score 6):

You can pass multiple args to log:

```
console.log("story", name, "story");
```

Answer (score 4):

`%j` works for only Node.js. `%j` converts a value to a JSON string and inserts it.

```
console.log('%j new messages for', 7, 'john')
// 7 new messages for john
```

#### More string substitutions here:

- https://exploringjs.com/impatient-js/ch_console.html

#### Docs:

- Chrome: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/console-write#string_substitution_and_formatting
- Firefox: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console#Using_string_substitutions
- IE: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/debugger/javascript-console-commands?view=vs-2019#ConsoleLog
- Node.js: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/debugger/javascript-console-commands?view=vs-2019#ConsoleLog
- Spec: https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#formatter

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you want.

`console.log("story "+name+" story")`
 will [concatenate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concatenation) the strings together and print that. For me, I use this because it is easier to see what is going on.

Using `console.log("story",name,"story")` is similar to concatenation however, it seems to run something like this:

```
 var text = ["story", name, "story"];
 console.log(text.join(" "));
```

This is pushing all of the items in the array together, separated by a space: `.join(" ")`

Answer (score 1):

Both `console.log("story" + name + "story")` and `console.log("story", name, "story")` works just fine as mentioned in earlier answers.

I will still suggest of having a habit of `console.log("story", name, "story")`, because, if trying to print the object contents, like json object, having `"story" + objectVariable + "story"` will convert it into string.

This will have output like : `"story" [object Object] "story"`.

Just a good practice.

Comment: Then why are you suggesting "," one. As it will just print [object object]. Mostly, we want string version which will get frmo "+". Right?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use printf style of formatting arguments. It is available in at least Chrome, Firefox/Firebug and node.js.

```
var name = prompt("what is your name?");

console.log("story %s story", name);
```

It also supports %d for formatting numbers

Answer (score 0):

there are several ways but most common is:

1. string concatenation

   var name = "someOne"

   console.log("your Name " + name)

here the + operator adds it

2.second method uses template strings

```
var name = 'someOne'
console.log(`your name ${name}`)
```

remember to use backticks(`) instead of quotes and enter your variable in ${variable}

Answer (score -4):

You can use the backslash to include both the story and the players name in one line.

var name=prompt("what is your name?");
console.log("story"\name\"story");