# Showing Value in console.log

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I make it so that I can show in `console.log()` what the value of `inputName` is.  I am currently getting nothing - what have I missed?

**Code:**

```
$(function(){


$.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';

  var inputName = $(this).data("title");

$('.updateField').editable({
    type: 'text',
    url: '/post',    
    pk: 1,    
    placement: 'top',
    title: 'Enter public name',
     toggle:'manual'    
});

$('.edit').click(function(e){    
       e.stopPropagation();
       console.log("inputName");
       $('.updateField').editable('toggle');
       $('.edit').hide();
});
    $(document).on('click', '.editable-cancel, .editable-submit', function(){
        $('.edit').show();
    })        
//ajax emulation. Type "err" to see error message
$.mockjax({
    url: '/post',
    responseTime: 100,
    response: function(settings) {
        if(settings.data.value == 'err') {
           this.status = 500;  
           this.responseText = 'Validation error!'; 
        } else {
           this.responseText = '';  
        }
    }
}); 

});
```

Comment: Please search SO for *console log variable javascript* to get related answers. Refer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16600925/how-can-i-add-a-variable-to-console-log

Comment: @Developer107 I clicked once I had posted this :)

Comment: i hope this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/fjsyxa2d/) will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the quotes: `console.log(inputName);`

Comment: Thanks,  it now gives me a response of `inputName` and wont show the var do I have to move that line within the click?

Comment: `console.log("inputName",inputName);`