# Concatenate a Javascript function and a string

Tags: javascript

I am trying to concatenate the result returned by a function to a simple string, both are declared inside the same object.
Example:

```
var hello = {
  how: function(){
    return ' are you';
  },
    ans: 'how',
    answer: 'how' + this.how() 
};

console.log(hello.how()); //works
console.log(hello.ans); //works
console.log(hello.answer); //doesnt work
```

Here is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o2jrr2bj/1/)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: answer will need to be a function...

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16600925/how-can-i-add-a-variable-to-console-log

Comment: if you want to use `this` like you do, than `hello` has to be an constructor function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use a constructor function to create the object, something like this:

```js
var hello = new function() {
  this.how = function(){
     return ' are you';
  },
  this.ans = 'how',
  this.answer = 'how' + this.how() 
};

console.log(hello.how()); //works
console.log(hello.ans); //works
console.log(hello.answer); //doesnt work
```

Comment: Thank you, both @Nil and your answer work, now my question is, which one is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var hello = {
  how: function(){
    return ' are you';
  },
    ans: 'how',
    answer: function(){
      return 'how' + this.how()
    }
};

console.log(hello.how()); //works
console.log(hello.ans); //works
console.log(hello.answer()); //now works
```